# Cassandra import/update creates many SSTables and doesn't compact

Tags: cassandra

I am having a 3 nodes cluster.

After inserting and updating 150K records into a CF, Cassandra reads start to timeout when reading records using pagination.

I am using the Leveled Compaction strategy for this particular table but when looking at the tablestats of this table, I get 0 for each SSTable level

SSTable count: 38
SSTables in each level: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Is this normal, why doesn't it compact the SSTables ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your logs?

Comment: First, we fixed it by running nodetool compact and restart each node one after the other. I read that it is not recommended to do this manually as it creates very large SSTables.

Comment: The other path we are looking at is that there might be not enough RAM on the node. We have 8GB of RAM, allocating the default value for Cassandra which is 1/4 I think.